# TimerTrigger doesn't always fire in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm experiencing `TimerTrigger` not actually triggering in multiple of my Azure Functions. The flow always looks similar to this:

[image: Timers]

As shown in the log statements, this timer is configured to trigger every 5 minutes (`0 */5 * * * *`). It triggers 5:10, 5:15, ... 5:40. But then on 5:45 no trigger. The same goes for 5:50. Then at 5:51 it "wakes up". I have `RunOnStartup = true` on my trigger, so this is probably caused by the function app being started.

My function app is consumption based, why I would expect the app to simply run on another machine if the current machine is shot down or in other ways unavailable. The app is running on Azure Functions version 3.

Am I missing something here, or does anyone experience similar issues?

Comment: there is already an answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67106453/14973743). may be at 5.40 when it ran did it run for longer than 5.45 causing it to "seem to" miss ? I doubt it, since your every-5-min func may not be doing any such long-running work...just check the possibilities.

Comment: Hello @ThomasArdal, Is this running on production environment..

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Good point. I'll try to log when the function is done too to see if it's a performance issues. I double it though, since the function doesn't do much. But worth a shoot.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT It's running on Azure, yes.

Comment: Taken from documentation (in a BIG, RED box): Don't set `runOnStartup` to true in production. Using this setting makes code execute at highly unpredictable times. In certain production settings, these extra executions can result in significantly higher costs for apps hosted in a Consumption plan.

Comment: Could you please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python#configuration) once

Comment: @rickvdbosch In most other functions I would agree. The only purpose of this particular function is to log a heartbeat to alert me when if a function app isn't running. So, in this case, executing this more often than every 5 minutes is not a problem. I guess the higher cost refer to the function being triggered more than configured through the corn settings.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, There is no specific reason for the timer trigger not firing properly within the given time.

Few of the workaround we can follow,

I have not faced the similar issue yet, would suggest you to please try to restart/refresh your function app.
or, *It may be due to of the sync issue with the function which is not happening properly*.

As suggested by @*Anand Sowmithiran* the [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099292/timer-trigger-function-app-is-missing-few-runs/67106453#67106453), @MayankBargali-MSFT suggest  about [***singleton***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#singleton-locks) lock *i,e*;

> *TimerTrigger uses the Singleton feature of the WebJobs SDK to ensure*
> *that only a single instance of your triggered function is running at*
> *any given time. When the JobHost starts up, for each of your*
> *TimerTrigger functions a blob lease (the Singleton Lock) is taken*.
> *This distributed lock ensures that only a single instance of your*
> *scheduled function is running at any time. If the blob for that*
> *function is not currently leased, the function will acquire the lease*
> *and start running on schedule immediately. If the blob lease cannot be*
> *acquired, it generally means that another instance of that function is*
> *running, so the function is not started in the current host.*

Also please *try to set `runonstartup` to false to check whether its behaving the same or not as provided the MS DOC in comment.*

For more information Please refer the below links :-

- **MS Q&A**| [***Azure Timer Trigger not firing***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/526830/azure-timer-trigger-not-firing.html)
- **GitHub** | [***azure timer function not executing all of sudden***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7159)